# ipython notebook --pylab inline: zooming of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Is it possible to zoom into a plot if inline is activated? Especially regarding to 3d-plots rotating and zooming is a necessary feature.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Now thanks to [mpld3](http://mpld3.github.io/) it's super easy to enable zooming in inline plots!

All you have to do is install mpld3 (`pip install mpld3`), and then add this to your notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
```

Now your plots will get a toolbar menu at the bottom left, in which you can enable mouse zooming :)

Comment: It seems 3D plots are not supported yet : https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/223

Comment: This is great, but one should add that with some of the heavier duty plots (plots containing millions of points, for instance), it is very slow.

Comment: I implemented this in my Jupyter Notebook 4.2.2 and zooming in caused the figure to go blank.  Adding origin='lower' as an argument to the imshow() call fixed it.  (e.g. imshow(res, origin='lower', cmap = cm.gray))

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm getting `Json serialization error`

Comment: It rather slowed down my kernel... extremely.

Answer (score 111):

You can now use `%matplotlib notebook` instead of `%matplotlib inline` and you'll be able to interact with your plots.

Comment: This a great solution. If you try it and it doesn't work, check your version of matplotlib. I think this was introduced in version 1.5

Comment: Doesn't work as well as I'd hoped with subplots; can zoom and pan for an individual subplot but can't increase/decrease the size of the entire plot image. Which, to be fair, wasn't the original question asked above.

Comment: @ijoseph you can increase the size of the entire image as well. Just drag the right bottom corner of the plot..

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes ah. I didn't see that because my initial `figsize` was set to be so large that the resizing corner was off the visible area of the page. An eventual [workaround was increasing the width of the notebook area entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058270/588437).

Comment: You may need to restart your notebook if you already called %matplotlib inline

Comment: I have 4 charts in my notebook, in separate cells. This places the last executed chart in first drawn one. Anyone else facing this? My matplot v2.1.1

Comment: I get the error "Javascript Error: IPython is not define"

Comment: @Ben: This is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56416229/1804173). Looks like `%matplotlib notebook` is outdated, and `ipympl` + `%matplotlib widget` is the modern approach.

Answer (score 14):

*mpld3* slowed down the execution of my notebooks. I found it better to use the [nbagg](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#the-nbagg-backend) backend that provides the same interactive tools but also allows to save graphs by the right-click menu:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('nbagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I honestly think this is the best answer, looks way better than mpld3 and more features.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I agree with @bznein in the sense it is cleaner, works by default and does the trick.

Comment: With this option, plots do not even show up for me

Answer (score 10):

At present, the closest you can come is to redraw it at a larger size using the `figsize` function. It expects dimensions in inches, which caught me out the first time I tried to use it.

There are some plants for a rich backend that would allow plots to be manipulated live, using HTML5, but I think it will be a few more months before that's ready.

If you're using the notebook on your local computer, for now the easiest option might be not to use inline mode, so the plots pop up as separate windows.

Comment: Yes it is - with a recent version of matplotlib, you can now select the nbagg backend.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.use('nbagg')` didnt work for me either. I did find `mdplt3` quite slow. Instead of zooming, I ended up resizing my figure (making it big), using this post: [Plot width settings in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589119/plot-width-settings-in-ipython-notebook)