# How can I open the interactive matplotlib window in IPython notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython with `--pylab=inline` and would sometimes like to quickly switch to the interactive, zoomable matplotlib GUI for viewing plots (the one that pops up when you plot something in a terminal Python console). How could I do that? Preferably without leaving or restarting my notebook.

The problem with inline plots in IPy notebook is that they are of a limited resolution and I can't zoom into them to see some smaller parts. With the maptlotlib GUI that starts from a terminal, I can select a rectangle of the graph that I want to zoom into and the axes adjust accordingly. I tried experimenting with

```
from matplotlib import interactive
interactive(True)
```

and

```
interactive(False)
```

but that didn't do anything. I couldn't find any hint online either.

Comment: Another possible solution to your original problem is enabling zooming in your inline plots, which is now possible as i've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22949003/145823

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook`    works

Answer (score 196, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html), you should be able to switch back and forth like this:

```
In [2]: %matplotlib inline 
In [3]: plot(...)

In [4]: %matplotlib qt  # wx, gtk, osx, tk, empty uses default
In [5]: plot(...)
```

and that will pop up a regular plot window (a restart on the notebook may be necessary).

Comment: It's `%pylab qt`. Not working in OS X. Maybe in Ubuntu it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't switch to and fro. If you try to switch after having started with pylab=inline or pylab=qt, you get:

This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the the backend has already been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot, or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

Comment: I downvoted this because it didn't work for me, and still doesn't, but apparently this is [issue 1927](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1927) and it should have been fixed with [merge 2179](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2179). @yarox, if you edit your answer to incorporate this info I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: It now works (at least in CentOS6 Linux with v1.0.0 of ipython)

Comment: works fine here on OSX as well, using ipython v1.1.0 and MPL 1.3.0

Comment: I've got it working in OSX 10.8 and python 1.1.0 as well.  BTW I just put %pylab qt in the first line of a cell that was plotting correctly and the window popped out when I ran the cell again.

Comment: Works for me now (2014-08) using current release of Python 2.7 on Win7 x64.

Comment: @VickyT doing so is crashing my notebook.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8.1 and Python 2.7. When I start a notebook with command ipython notebook. Then I need to use %pylab qt and not %pylab inline. Maybe this is something to do with Google Chrome, but inline does not work for me...

Comment: Has anyone found a reason this works for some and not for others?  I'm using mac osx, anaconda distr., and I can't get this to work.

Comment: Pretty sure that `%pylab` is deprecated, you should use `%matplotlib` instead.

Comment: `%matplotlib osx` works for me on my mac (instead of `qt`).

Comment: Works on Ubuntu as of Aug 2016

Comment: Neither `qt` nor `osx` is working for me. OS X client with Python 3 kernel running on remote Ubuntu server.

Comment: @sudo The issue is that the GUI windows are opening on your kernel server not on your client.

Comment: @CharlBotha -- In my experience, you *can* use "%matplotlib inline" and "%matplotlib qt" to toggle back and forth, *BUT ONLY* if you never call matplotlib.use() (and also don't call anything that calls matplotlib.use()).  Once you do that, something gets set internally that interferes with what the "%matplotlib" magic is doing.

Comment: I am suprised, it is version/ system-dependent: On Ubuntu running Jupyter / IPython 5.7.4 (Ptyhon 3.7.3) and in firefox, I need the following lines to enable interactive plots in a popup-window:
    %matplotlib qt
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')

Comment: This only works if you have the proper gui toolkit installed. For example, to make "%matplotlib qt" work, I had to install pyqt5 first via "pip install pyqt5"

Answer (score 86):

If all you want to do is to switch from inline plots to interactive and back (so that you can pan/zoom), it is better to use %matplotlib magic.

```
#interactive plotting in separate window
%matplotlib qt
```

and back to html

```
#normal charts inside notebooks
%matplotlib inline
```

%pylab magic imports a bunch of other things and may even result in a conflict. It does "from pylab import *".

You also can use new notebook backend (added in matplotlib 1.4):

```
#interactive charts inside notebooks, matplotlib 1.4+
%matplotlib notebook
```

If you want to have more interactivity in your charts, you can look at **mpld3** and **bokeh**. mpld3 is great, if you don't have ton's of data points (e.g. <5k+) and you want to use normal matplotlib syntax, but more interactivity, compared to %matplotlib notebook . Bokeh can handle lots of data, but you need to learn it's syntax as it is a separate library.

Also you can check out pivottablejs (pip install pivottablejs)

```
from pivottablejs import pivot_ui
pivot_ui(df)
```

However cool interactive data exploration is, it can totally mess with reproducibility. It has happened to me, so I try to use it only at the very early stage and switch to pure inline matplotlib/seaborn, once I got the feel for the data.

Comment: `Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: notebook. Using qt instead.` for `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: `ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding` for the qt magic command

Comment: @mLstudent33 Got the same warning message, restarting the kernel and running `%matplotlib notebook` again worked for me (using IPython 7.19.0).

Answer (score 35):

Starting with matplotlib 1.4.0 there is now an an interactive backend for use in the notebook

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

There are a few version of IPython  which do not have that alias registered, the fall back is:

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

If that does not work update you IPython.

To play with this, goto [tmpnb.org](http://tmpnb.org)

and paste

```
%matplotlib notebook

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index,
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df = df.cumsum()
df.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

into a code cell (or just modify the existing python demo notebook)

Answer (score 13):

You can use

`%matplotlib qt`

If you got the error `ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding` then install PyQt5 as: `pip install PyQt5` and it works for me.

Comment: Very helpful when I get `[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 9b3ed8f3535aed9` error on other backends.

Answer (score 7):

A better solution for your problem might be the [Charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library. It enables you to use the excellent [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) javascript library to make beautiful and interactive plots. Highcharts uses the HTML `svg` tag so all your charts are actually vector images.

Some features:

- Vector plots which you can download in .png, .jpg and .svg formats so you will never run into resolution problems
- Interactive charts (zoom, slide, hover over points, ...)
- Usable in an IPython notebook
- Explore hundreds of data structures at the same time using the asynchronous plotting capabilities.

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the library*

Comment: A pretty nice library! I'll be sure to try it out :)

Comment: Thanks! Let me know what you think on github and submit an issue if you experience any problems :)

Comment: While this answer is definitely relevant, I would not necessarily call it "a better solution". That is what caused a downvote in the past, most likely.

Comment: Downvoted, since this post does not tell me how I can actually use the Charts library to open an interactive plot window.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using ipython in "jupyter QTConsole" from Anaconda at www.continuum.io/downloads on 5/28/20117.

Here's an example to flip back and forth between a separate window and an inline plot mode using ipython magic.

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data to plot
>>> x1 = [x for x in range(20)]

# Show in separate window
>>> %matplotlib
>>> plt.plot(x1)
>>> plt.close() 

# Show in console window
>>> %matplotlib inline
>>> plt.plot(x1)
>>> plt.close() 

# Show in separate window
>>> %matplotlib
>>> plt.plot(x1)
>>> plt.close() 

# Show in console window
>>> %matplotlib inline
>>> plt.plot(x1)
>>> plt.close() 

# Note: the %matplotlib magic above causes:
#      plt.plot(...) 
# to implicitly include a:
#      plt.show()
# after the command.
#
# (Not sure how to turn off this behavior
# so that it matches behavior without using %matplotlib magic...)
# but its ok for interactive work...
```

Comment: When I try to use `%matplotlib` I get an error which ends with `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'`

Comment: I get the exact same problem as user3731622. What can be done? This is for most of the answers on this page

Comment: @mkheifetz @user3731622 You may need to install the package: `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5` or `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5`

Answer (score 4):

Restart kernel and clear output (if not starting with new notebook), then run

```
%matplotlib tk
```

For more info go to [Plotting with matplotlib](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#plotting-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I uninstalled pyqt5, which was installed via apt. Then, I installed it again via pip. This solved the import error.

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-pyqt5

pip install PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.use('nbagg')` doesn't work in new version of matplotlib.

Instead we use magic function as

```
%matplotlib nbagg
```

it works in new versions of matplot lib (>3.0).

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib nbagg
```