# Codes in Ipython vs Pycharm

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am a newbie and the following question may be dumb and not well written. 
I tried the following block of codes in Ipython:

```
%pylab qt5
x = randn(100,100)
y = mean(x,0)
import seaborn
plot(y)
```

And it delivered a plot. Everything was fine.

However, when I copied and pasted those same lines of codes to Pycharm and tried running, syntax error messages appeared.

For instance,

- %pylab was not recognized.
- Then I tried to import numpy and matplotlib one by one. But then,
  randn(.,.) was not recognized.

Comment: `%pylab` is a magic function in [`ipython`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) this is why it doesn't work in Pycharm

Comment: How about calling functions like "randn"? I think the standard is np.random or so? 

So, codes written with Pycharm editor and can run there can run in Ipython, but not vice versa?

Comment: You will need to do `np.random.randn()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20961287/1028589

Comment: Ipython magic functions only work in ipython

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPython/Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm by following this guide:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html

You may modify code like the snippet below in order to run in PyCharm:

```
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy import mean
import seaborn

x = randn(10, 10)
y = mean(x, 0)

seaborn.plt.plot(x)
seaborn.plt.show()
```