# difference between '%pip' and '!pip' in python jupyter notebook and colab

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

what is the difference between '!pip' and '%pip'? We can use both of them in jupyter notebook and google colab. But we can not use the simple 'pip' there, can we?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`%pip` is a **magic** function and works mostly the same like `pip`. You can use other **magic** functions in jupyter which you can list with `%lsmagic`

(https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-lsmagic)

Using `!` allows to run commands like `ls` or `pip` or what you have available on your OS.

Colab is just like jupyter so you can run native `pip` like `pip install tensorflow`.

See related answers:

- [What is the meaning of exclamation and question marks in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498226/what-is-the-meaning-of-exclamation-and-question-marks-in-jupyter-notebook)
- [What is %pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961287/what-is-pylab)
- [How do I install Python packages in Google's Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab)

Comment: [It may work differently in virtual environments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70604999/900394)

Answer (score 7):

`%pip` will install the package in the virtual environment where the current notebook kernel is running. While `!pip` will install the package in the base environment. If you are using Python virtual environment (as you should!), you should use `%pip`.

Comment: If you are using conda virtual environment, always use %pip.

Comment: Thanks. In jupyter notebook, I have seabon not working using "!pip install seaborn" but work by "%pip install seabron"