# Is there an advantage of using `%` over `!` in jupyter when the same command exists for both?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, jupyter, jupyter-lab

For example when I use `!pip install ...` VSCode suggests me to use `%pip install ...`. Similarly there is a version of `mv` for both `!` and `%`. Is there an advantage to use one over the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `%pip` will properly resolve the appropriate virtual environment (the one that is used by the current kernel) in most edge cases, while `!pip` will not and you may end up installing packages in incorrect locations.

Some references:

- [Authoritative statement from creator of IPython/Jupyter](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-desktop/issues/234#issuecomment-928484514)
- [Blog post from creator of `%pip` magic](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)
- [The actual pull request that introduced the `%pip` and `%conda` magics](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/11524)

Comment: Could you point where I can read more?

Comment: I added some references. There are many scenarios where `!pip` will end up different from `%pip` (remote kernels, conda/pip mixup, JupyterLab Desktop, nb_conda_kernels, etc) and I don't feel like it warrants enumerating all possible cases in the answer; just don't use `!pip` ever and you will be fine.

Comment: @krassowski very clear explanation. as I mention also in my answer ! should be written in IPython notebook before any shell command you want to run in jupyter notebook while Magic commands are specific to the IPython kernel in jupyter but with more flexibility and power.
check the references in my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference that exclamation point `!` should be written in IPython notebook before any shell command you want to run in your notebook. Check [Shell Assignment](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment) in the docs for more of an explanation.

> While Magics are specific to and provided by the IPython kernel. To
> work properly, Magics must use a syntax element which is not valid in
> the underlying language. For example, the IPython kernel uses the `%`
> syntax element for Magics as `%` is not a valid unary operator in
> Python.

In addition to that you can create and register your own Magics with IPython. Also you can find many user defined Magics on PyPI.

So we can say that magic `%` commands provide more functionality which is defined in IPython kernel than just the standard shell commands.

For more info on magic commands check this [official reference](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).