# python package installation !pip and -q

Tags: pip

```
!pip install -q hvplot
```

Why is there a `"!"`? What does `"-q"` mean? If I use Windows Command Prompt, shall I use the following code instead to make it work

```
pip install hvplot
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

! stands for history expansion in unix read more about it [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/).

-q stands for quiet it results in less code being logged in the terminal, you can also do --quiet for quiet

Comment: Thanks, Harsh! I am not using unix. I am using windows. I guess I should type pip instead of !pip. Correct?

Comment: @Michael yes but if you want you can try -q but it is not neccessary.

Comment: `!` could stand for history expansion in some unix shells but not in that case. Currently it means "run the command in a shell instead of Python" in a Jupyter Notebook: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65547021/7976758

Comment: @phd the question nowhere mentions jupyter notebooks

Comment: That's because the question is quite bad. The OP saw somewhere the syntax without understanding it's a syntax for Notebooks.