# What does the % in load_ext mean in python

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

There is a lot of discussion of `%load_ext` magic in Python (e.g. here https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/index.html)

One thing that has always confused me though: what is the % doing / what does it mean?

Why isn't the relevant code just called by `load_ext`

Comment: Well if you enter something in a jupyter cell jupyter has to know you're talking about a jupyter command rather than Julia, Python or R code. You tell it with `%` or `%%`. E.g. If you want to make it run your a function multiple times and give you statistics on how long it took you could do `%timeit my_function()`.

Answer (score 3):

From the IPython docs, [Built-in magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html):

> Note To Jupyter users: Magics are specific to and provided by the IPython kernel. Whether Magics are available on a kernel is a decision that is made by the kernel developer on a per-kernel basis. To work properly, Magics must use a syntax element which is not valid in the underlying language. For example, the IPython kernel uses the `%` syntax element for Magics as `%` is not a valid unary operator in Python. However, `%` might have meaning in other languages.

(By the way, [`%load_ext`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-load_ext) is covered in brief on the same page.)

---

Related questions:

- [What is %pylab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961287/what-is-pylab)
- [Purpose of "%matplotlib inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline)