# Folium map not displaying in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder, folium

The title says it all : I can't get Spyder to display a map with `folium`.

Here is what I get :

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
m
```

No error (and no map), just this :

> < folium.folium.Map at 0xd03fcf8 >

```
m.render() # No idea what .render() it's supposed to do, 
# but "render" sounds like maybe it could display the map, so I tried it.
# But it prints nothing

m.render
```

> < bound method LegacyMap.render of < folium.folium.Map object at 0x000000000D03FCF8 > >

Any idea ?

Thanks

(Note : I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36700565/4348534), with no success)

Comment: This link may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969991/folium-map-not-displaying/38797877#38797877

Answer (score 15):

If you have a map `m` you could use:

```
m.save("mymap.html")
```

It saves your map in your working directory as html. You still have to open it manually in Chrome/IE. The advantage of this is that you can e-mail your map to anyone you want, even if he/she does not have python on his/her computer.

Answer (score 5):

Also open the map directly from the spyder ide by importing webbrowser(provided you've install the webbrowser package).

```py
import webbrwoser
webbrowser.open_tab("map.html")
```

Comment: ```webbrowser.open_new_tab('test.html')``` as of May 18, 2023. also, ```webbrowser``` is an embedded package in Python (no need to install it)

Answer (score 3):

It seems `folium` generates web based maps, and those can't be rendered by Spyder. So you need to use the Jupyter notebook if you want to work with `folium`.

Comment: Even though I can have `mplleaflet` display leaflet maps in a new chrome tab ? (Not sure if it's the same thing)

Comment: If it opens a new tab for you from Spyder, it should work. But the map won't be shown directly on Spyder.

Comment: Yes, that is what it does with `mplleaflet`. But I can't get it to do it with `folium`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that.