# can't plot the map with folium

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, spyder, folium

I folowed the documentation here: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html
but I can't plot the map.

```
import folium


m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
m
```

the output is just :

```
Out[67]: <folium.folium.Map at 0x263ecc9a908>
```

PS: branca-0.4.1,  folium-0.11.0,  python 3.5

[image]

I think that the problem is due to the use of spyder insteed of jupiter ! 

 Is there a way to plot it in spyder ?

 any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you try running the cell again?

Comment: `In [68]: m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])<br>

In [69]: m<br>
Out[69]: <folium.folium.Map at 0x263ecc9a940>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is folium generates maps that are web-based. Hence, spyder fails to render it. This is a possible work-around* -

```
import folium
import webbrowser

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
m.save("map_1.html")
webbrowser.open("map_1.html")
```

A similar question was posted on StackOverflow - [Folium map not displaying in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340483/folium-map-not-displaying-in-spyder), but the answers didn't seem to exactly solve the issue, hence I posted my answer over here.

Comment: thank you it works for me, I wanted a map in the form of a figure so that I can return it in a dialog system. But an html solution can do the goal ;)