# Jupyter Notebook + Matplotlib; Freeze on plot.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pygtk

**OBJECTIVE**

- Use Matplotlib to plot the state of Texas

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


map = Basemap(projection='merc', lat_0 = 57, lon_0 = -135,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 0.1,
    llcrnrlon=-106.65, llcrnrlat=25.83,
    urcrnrlon=-93.50, urcrnrlat=36.50)

map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawstates()
map.drawcountries()
map.fillcontinents(color = 'white')
map.drawmapboundary()


plt.show(block = False)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**DEBUG**

- Apparently [changing backend helps](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6908), however `matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')` yields the following error `"Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed"`
- Looked online for solutions, read you had to install [PyGTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python), however, when installing, I receive the following error: `Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows.` (after inputting `pip install PyGTK`)
- Additionally, despite calling `matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')`, I receive the error `matplotlib.use() has no effect
  because the backend has already been chosen;
  matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
  or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.`.

**ISSUE**

1. Cannot properly install packages necessary to prevent matplotlib from running in a continual loop. Am I missing something here? Are there workarounds?
2. Why, despite calling `matplotlib('QT4Agg')` before importing matplotlib, I receive the error (bullet point #3) listed above?

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/4779/files might clarify what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this in Jupyter Notebook or something of the sort? Usually you shouldn't be able to do

```
matplotlib.use('QT4Agg')
import matplotlib
```

in that order, as matplotlib wouldn't be in the namespace. Change the order, then restart your Jupyter kernel or dump all this into a *.py* file.

In Jupyter, you should be able to call

```
%matplotlib qt4
```

before importing *matplotlib* to set the backend instead of calling *use()*.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up having success with the following tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261903/how-can-i-open-the-interactive-matplotlib-window-in-ipython-notebook