# Show plot in new, interactive window in jupyter with python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I just installed a python 3.6 kernel for my Jupyter notebook. In the past, with python 2.7, I was able to look at interactive plots in a separate window (i.e., not embedded below a cell in the notebook) by simply using the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.show()
```

But now if I use this same code in the python 3.6 kernel, it appears just as if I had used

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in python 2.7: it's embedded in the notebook below the plt.show() command.

Can someone tell me how to use interactive plots in a python 3 Jupyter kernel?

UPDATE:

I discovered that

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

will give me an inline and interactive plot. Which is adequate for my purposes, but for the future, I would still like to know if it is possible to make new plotting windows as I originally asked.

UPDATE 2:

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261903/how-can-i-open-the-interactive-matplotlib-window-in-ipython-notebook) offers the solution to use

```
%matplotlib qt
```

to restore the separate-window-plotting feature. But it is appears to pre-date python 3, and when I try the command, it returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

FINAL UPDATE:

Apparently this will give me the functionality I wanted:

```
%matplotlib tk
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the version of python. Probably something else got updated as well.

Comment: Thanks for finding that other thread. But my question was not answered by it. See my UPDATE 2.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, ok I've actually found that the solution was on the page you linked. At the very bottom. Thanks!

Comment: `%matplotlib qt` is one of the options you have. If you don't have PyQt available, you can use the other menionned options `# wx, gtk, osx, tk, empty uses default` (this is mentionned in the very first answer there). Note that "empty" means `%matplotlib` without anything behind.

Comment: What isn't mentionned there is that you could try `%matplotlib qt5`, because python 3.6 would probably have pyqt5 if any.

Comment: Yes, using just %matplotlib gives me exactly the functionality I originally wanted. And yes, %matplotlib qt5 does work, and it also lets me change the axes from the GUI which is pretty neat. Thanks for your help.