# No plot displayed by using matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I needed to make a plot using `pandas` and `matplotlib`. I am using `python3.9` and tried the code in `IPython`. The `matplotlib` version is 3.3.2, and that of `pandas` 1.1.5. What I get, is unreadable text showed in the terminal with no plot being generated. Here is the code:

```
#Three lines to make the compiler able to draw:
 import sys
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('Agg')

 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

 df["Duration"].plot(kind = 'hist')

 plt.show()

 #Two  lines to make the compiler able to draw:
 plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

What is the reason behind ?

Comment: Something important is to call `plt.savefig(...)` before `plt.show()`, because as a side effect `plt.show()` erases the plot.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to also call `plt.savefig(...)`  at the end as I have done it ? An argument is required for the `plt.savefig(...)`. What should I put as argument ?

Comment: To just display the plot, you normally only need `plt.show()`. `plt.savefig(filename)` is used to save a plot to a file.  Where does the idea of using `sys.stdout.buffer` come from? Is it some really old code? Or are you using a very unusual environment?

Comment: What happens if you leave out `matplotlib.use('Agg')` (and restart the environment) to let matplotlib work with its defaults?  If you are running jupyter, you may need `%matplotlib inline` (just an image) or `%matplotlib notebook` (interactive plot).  See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261903/how-can-i-open-the-interactive-matplotlib-window-in-ipython-notebook) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: I only need to see the plot and not save it to a file. I followed your suggestion. I got the plot saved in the working directory folder. When I omit the last two lines, I do not get the unreadable text I was complaining before. Thanks for your suggestion. If I do not save the plot via `plt.savefig('filename')`, the plot is not saved and not displayed. I only get the following message, which I also get if I save the plot: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.

Comment: If I leave out `matplotlib.use('Agg')`, nothing new happens, meaning that it is superfluous: if I had included `plt.savefig(...)`, I will have saved the plot, if not, I do not get the plot at all. In either cases I get the usual message as previously:`UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.` In no instance I can get the plot only displayed.

Comment: Well. you need to restart the environment (in Jupyter: clicking kernel->restart), otherwise the old `matplotlib.use('Agg')` stays active.