# Zoom an inline 3D matplotlib figure *without* using the mouse?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, zooming, matplotlib-3d

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904912/how-to-set-camera-position-for-3d-plots-using-python-matplotlib) explains how to change the "camera position" of a 3D plot in matplotlib by specifying the elevation and azimuth angles. `ax.view_init(elev=10,azim=20)`, for example.

**Is there a similar way to specify the *zoom* of the figure numerically -- i.e. without using the mouse?**

The only relevant question I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655217/ipython-notebook-pylab-inline-zooming-of-a-plot), but the accepted answer to that involves installing another library, which then also requires using the mouse to zoom.

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I'm not talking about changing the figure size (using `fig.set_size_inches()` or similar). The figure size is fine; the problem is that the plotted stuff only takes up a small part of the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest solution to `view_init` is setting `ax.dist` directly. According to the docs for [`get_proj`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.get_proj) "dist is the distance of the eye viewing point from the object point". The [initial value is currently hardcoded](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L948) with `dist = 10`. Lower values (above 0!) will result in a zoomed in plot.

*Note*: This behavior is not really documented and may change. Changing the limits of the axes to plot only the relevant parts is probably a better solution in most cases. You could use [`ax.autoscale(tight=True)`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.autoscale) to do this conveniently.

## Working IPython/Jupyter example:

```py
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import display
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Grab some test data.
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

# Plot a basic wireframe.
ax.view_init(90, 0)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
plt.close()

from ipywidgets import interact

@interact(dist=(1, 20, 1))
def update(dist=10):
    ax.dist = dist
    display(fig)
```

## Output

`dist = 10`

[image: image for dist = 10]

`dist = 5`

[image: image for dist = 5]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would provide an updated answer for anyone looking.

The `ax.dist` argument is being deprecated.  The preferred way to do this is to use the 'zoom' argument in the `ax.set_box_aspect()` function.

For example:

```py
ax.set_box_aspect((1, 1, 1), zoom=2.0)
```

This needs to be set before calling the figure canvas manager's `show()` function.