# How to zoom on an interactive 3D plot in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm creating a 3D scatter plot using matplotlib and would like to interact with it in jupyter notebook by panning and zooming. However, when I try to use the zoom button on the interactive plot, it acts the same way as the pan button. Is there a way to zoom on interactive 3D plots in jupyter notebook? Here's a MWE that reproduces the issue for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

np.random.seed(1000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

N = 100

ax.scatter(np.random.rand(N), np.random.rand(N), np.random.rand(N), '.')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655217/ipython-notebook-pylab-inline-zooming-of-a-plot

Answer (score 0):

The pan and zoom buttons in matplotlib 3D plots do not work at the moment, but should hopefully be enabled in matplotlib version 3.7 (if [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/23449) gets merged in). In the meantime, if you are using a mouse you should be able to rotate 3D plots with the left mouse button, pan using the middle mouse button, and zoom using the right mouse button.